# Need to provide addtional jars to for xsbt-web-plugin container

Tags: sbt, xsbt-web-plugin, webapp-runner

I am trying to run my war file using `xsbt-web-plugin`. My war itself does not contain `tomcat-jdbc-pool` jar and `javax-servlet-api`. I tried using `container` configuration. But sbt complains configuration does not exist.
If I use `provided` configuration, `webapp-runner` fails.

I am sure I am missing something. But unable to figure it out.

`WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: [javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of xsbt-web-plugin are you using?  Can you post the contents of your sbt build configuration?

The Tomcat plugin in xsbt-web-plugin relies on [webapp-runner](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner), which does not appear to bundle the `tomcat-jdbc` library.  You can add it via [`containerLibs in Tomcat`](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/4.0.x.md#tomcat-version):

```
enablePlugins(TomcatPlugin)

containerLibs in Tomcat += "org.apache.tomcat" % "tomcat-jdbc" % "8.5.15"
```

Comment: Thanks @earldouglas. It worked.
I am using version 4.0.1.

For some reason I thought containLibs is only for custom containers. Thanks for your help.